# Python; How do I test if something is in a list?

Tags: python

I was writing a code that will ask you to play a guessing game. It will ask you whether you want to play or not and proceed.

It was supposed to ask a number again if the entered value is not in the list but It is not working. I couldn't get it. Thx by now!

```
import random
import math
import time

repeat=True
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
gamestart=False
gamecontinue=True


def guess():
  chosennumber=random.choice(numbers)

  guessnumber=raw_input(">Guess the number I chose between 0 and 6:")

  if guessnumber==chosennumber and guessnumber in numbers:
    print ">Congratulations, I chose %d too!" % (int(chosennumber))
    print
  elif guessnumber!=chosennumber:
    print "That is not right."
    print "I chose %d." % (int(chosennumber))
    print

  elif not guessnumber in numbers:

    while not guessnumber in numbers:

        guessnumber=raw_input(">Please enter a number between 0 and 6:")


if raw_input(">Do you want to play guessing game? Y or N:") == "Y":

  gamestart=True

else:

  print "Okay, I will play myself."
  time.sleep(2)
  print "Bye :("


while gamestart==True and gamecontinue==True:

  guess()

  if raw_input (">Do you want to play again? Y or N:") == "N": 

    gamecontinue=False
    print "Okay, I will play myself."
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Bye :("
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for a question about a few lines. It can be helpful to write a small test program focusing on just the problem. Many times, you solve the problem yourself while writing it. But otherwise, it gives us something easy to spot the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I understand it but most of the time the things I face are all about the whole code itself so I consider posting the whole code. Otherwise people ussualy ask for the whole code. But Thx

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Look at the list chosennumber is not an integer, it is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you figured out what was the issue, good! but i have one more tip for you, a better approach to achieve this is check if the input is correct as soon is readed, if it is correct you keep going, if it not, you ask for it again right there:

```
while True:
    guessnumber=raw_input(">Guess the number I chose between 0 and 6:")
    if guessnumber in numbers:
        print "good!"
        break
    else:
        print "bad!"
```

and now you're sure that the input is correct so you only check:

```
if guessnumber==chosennumber:
    print ">Congratulations, I chose %d too!" % (int(chosennumber))
else:
    print "That is not right."
    print "I chose %d." % (int(chosennumber))
```

Comment: Late to answer but you changed my all thoughts about python, I don't know how didn't I face with a thing like this.

Comment: no problem, but this isn't just for python, this aplies to every language.. imagine that your first `if` and `elif` was a very much complex tast or condition to evaluate, you would go for all of them just for telling that he input was wrong at the end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you put two `elif` statements the first one will proceed first.

```
  elif guessnumber!=chosennumber:
    print "That is not right."
    print "I chose %d." % (int(chosennumber))
    print
```

This condition will be asked first. But if you look again at it whether the input (guessnumber) is in the list or not it will proceed. So if we want it to become a condition which we enter a number that is in a list but not matching with the chosen number, we will add another condition to elif statement.

code will be like this

```
elif guessnumber!=chosennumber and guessnumber in numbers:
```

Slight detail but good to keep in mind I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
if number not in numbers
```

That will do the trick
It checks if it is true that the selected number is in the list